# How to update JQuery in magneto 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

i am trying to update JQuery on mageneto 1 but i don't know complete steps can someone guide me for that

Answer (score 1):

You should not upgrade jquery. There is a high chance you will break something. Dependencies should be upgraded and tested by the core team.

Comment: but we need to upgrade it is there any possible way?